# c# Cannot create InlineKeyboardButton

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

I am creating a telegram bot, but I am unable to create any **InlineKeyboardButton** objects.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Telegram.Bot.Types.InlineKeyboardButtons;

namespace BuildAutomation.Controllers
{
    public class Test
    {
       public TestMethod()
    {
        var none = new InlineKeyboardButton("No", "build|no");
        var yes = "Yes";
        var betaControl = new InlineKeyboardButton(yes, "build|betacontrol");
        var betaNode = new InlineKeyboardButton(yes, "build|betanode");
        var betaBoth = new InlineKeyboardButton(yes, "build|betaboth");

        InlineKeyboardMarkup menu;

        menu = new InlineKeyboardMarkup(new[] { betaBoth, none });
    }
    }
}
```

I keep getting the error '**Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'InlineKeyboardButton'**. I realize that **InlineKeyboardButton** is an abstract class, but i see many examples creating an object of **InlineKeyboardButton**.

Did I miss something?

[example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41533074/how-to-create-inlinekeyboardmarkup-this-example)

[example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39884961/create-dynamic-keyboard-telegram-bot-in-c-sharp-mrroundrobin-api)

[example 3](https://github.com/TelegramBots/telegram.bot.examples/blob/master/Telegram.Bot.Examples.Echo/Program.cs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instantiation of `InlineKeyboardButton` directly was correct in **previous** versions.
There is a new commit for about one month ago which indicates that `InlineKeyboardButton` is made abstract from then on. You must use derived classes instead. `InlineKeyboardUrlButton`, `InlineKeyboardPayButton` and etc. are all derived from `InlineKeyboardButton`.
It seems that the examples' repository is not updated yet.

Check this link for more details about the mentioned commit:
https://github.com/TelegramBots/telegram.bot/commit/ddaa8b74e3ab5eab632dbe2e8916c2fe87b114a3

Answer (score 2):

Use `InlineKeyboardCallbackButt`on Example, `InlineKeyboardCallbackButton("Yes", "CallBackData")` instead of `InlineKeyboardButton("Yes", "CallbackData")`

Answer (score 0):

You couldn't create a new instance of abstraction class. So use sample bellow

```
 var KeyboardButons = new InlineKeyboardButton[][]
                {
                  new InlineKeyboardButton[]
                  {
                     InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("سفارش", callbackQueryData) ,
                     InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("بازگشت", "return")
                  }
                };

                var replyMarkup = new InlineKeyboardMarkup()
                {

                    InlineKeyboard = KeyboardButons
                };
```